# como hacer que un video avance hasta x segundos?

Tags: jquery, html5, html-video

tengo un video que que le quiero controlar el avance cada que se da click en uno de los textos.

```
<div class="video-content2">
    <video id="videoSlider" autoplay class="video" controlslist="nodownload" loop="">
      <source src="video_web_hibridos_1800x340.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <div class="controls-1">
        <p onclick="setCurTime()">Parte 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="controls-2">
        <p>Parte 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="controls-3">
        <p>Parte 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("videoSlider");

    function setCurTime() {
        var time = vid.currentTime = 5;
        if (time == 5) {
            vid.pause();
            console.log("display block");
        }
    }
</script>
```

aca me funciona de tal forma que si quiero que se ponga en el segundo 5 se avanza, pero lo quiero lograr es que avance hasta el segundo 5 y se detenga, ya que avanza hasta el segundo 5 de golpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo tengo un código algo raro que cumple esa función. Raro porque un tiempo necesitaba ésta función y conseguí  de algún sitio e hice copia pega, sin estudiarlo. Pero ahora te comparto y te servirá.

Nota. Si se agrega el atributo `controls` y si se hace play mediante el control, el evento no funciona. Solamente funciona con la función `onclick` del botón.

```js
function setCurTime() { // Recibe la función click

// Variables: video y temporizador
var video = document.getElementById("video"), temporizador;

video.addEventListener("play", function() {

    // Definir dentro de temporizador
    temporizador = setInterval(function() {

        // El tiempo de pause() y parar temporizador
        if(parseInt(video.currentTime) == 5) {
            clearInterval(temporizador);
            video.pause();
        }

    });

}, false);

// Al hace click, en setCurTime() el vídeo corre
video.play();
};
```

```html
<video id="video" autoplay style="background-color:#000;width:100%;display:block">
            <source src="">
        </video>
        <br><br>
        <button onclick="setCurTime()">Play demo</button>
```

Comment: Exactamente como lo necesitaba, muchas gracias.